# Can AppleScript be used to trigger a Quick Action (e. g. create PDF from selected files)?

Tags: applescript, pdf

The "Create PDF" Quick Action is much quicker and reliable than every other solution I have tested to create a single PDF from hundreds of images (.jpg or .png), be it Automator or a Python script based on the FPDF module. The issue is I have thousands of folders (all of which contain hoards of pictures waiting to be merged) to process ; I would thus like to programmatically perform the aforementioned Quick Action on each and every of them, that is open one folder after the other, select all files, and <s>in the darkness</s> bind them together. Any chance this could be done in AppleScript ? Of course I am open to solutions in other languages as well. Any piece of advice would be much appreciated,

thanks !

Comment: what do you mean by "bind them together".  You initially said you wanted to save each file as a PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! From let's say 300 .png or .jpg files I want to create one single PDF with 300 pages. I hope that's clearer.

Comment: I don't think you can trigger the built-in Quick Actions from an AppleScript: they reside inside the System folders and are quite different in character from created Quick Actions or Automator actions.
If I may, have you tried my python script? It's pretty fast, and you can tailor it to your needs. https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/blob/master/Automator_Scripts/image2pdf.py

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe how fast this script is, I have tailored it to my needs and it works like a charm. I will be eternally grateful for your help, this is a true game-changer for me !